# Como informo pro python que uma celula do excel esta em branco

Tags: python, pandas, pyautogui

Preciso informar o python que se a célula "Relação" estiver em **BRANCO**, ele pule pra próxima página e se estiver preenchida que ele preencha com o conteúdo da célula.
O código está funcionando normalmente quando a célula está preenchida, porém não funciona se a célula estiver em branco.
Segue código abaixo:

```
             import pyautogui
             import pandas as pd

             formulario = pd.read_excel(r'C:\formulario.xlsx', sheet_name='Planilha1')
             pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab')

             #se "Relação" está em branco, pular pra próxima página

             if formulario['Relação'] [0] == '' :
             pyautogui.hotkey('down')
             pyautogui.hotkey('tab')
             pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
             
             #se relção está preenchida, preencher com os dados contidos e pular pra proxima página.

             elif formulario['Relação'] [0] == 'Mãe/Pai':
             pyautogui.hotkey('tab')
             pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
             pyautogui.sleep(3)
             pyautogui.hotkey('tab')
             pyautogui.write(str(formulario['Sobrenome'] [0]))
             pyautogui.hotkey('tab')
             pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
```

minha planilha excel:

````
            ```A            B
       1-   Sobrenome     Relação
       2-    Nunes        Mãe/Pai```
````

Então gostaria de que quando o usuário deixasse o item "Relação" em **BRANCO** o sistema simplesmente ignorasse e pulasse pra próxima página.

OBS: Se eu colocar um ESPAÇO vazio na célula e colocar o código == ' ':

ele funciona. Porém com célula em branco e o código == '':
este não funciona de jeito nenhum.
Ja tentei:
== None:
== NaN:
== ['']:
== [('')]:
== "":
== (''):
== is None:

Comment: Você colocou o `pandas` como tag. Então pergunto: Porque você não está usando no método `to_excel()`?

Comment: Eu aprendi usando pandas, não conheço to_excel()
como ficaria esse comando usando ele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar **pd.isnull()**, esse método verifica se a series ou dataframe está vazio. Retorna True caso esteja e False caso contrário.

Observe um exemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', pd.NA]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

if pd.isnull(df['col_2'][3]): # Verifica se pd.isnull() retornou True
    print('Está vazio.')
else:
    print('Está preenchido.')
```

O retorno desse exemplo será um print descrevendo o status do objeto passado para o método **pd.isnull()**.

Comment: Sem palavras.... fiquei das 10 da manha até as 17 travado nisso...rs
Vi varios videos e foruns e nada resolvia ninguem mencionou esse pd.isnull()

Muito obrigado!!!! Destravei...kkk